# enable MSCHAP and MPPE for VPN connection

Tags: network-manager, vpn, pptp

I have setup a VPN configuration file, the connection is responding but in order to actually connect to it I need to enable MSCHAP, MSCHAPv2 and MPPE, just like the picture here:

[image]

The problem arises when I need to do this from the terminal since I only have ssh access. I added this to my `/etc/ppp/options.pptp`:

```
refuse-pap
refuse-eap
refuse-chap
#refuse-mschap
require-mppe-128
```

When I try to dial the connection `pon myvpn nodetach` I get this response:

```
Using interface ppp0
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
MPPE required, but MS-CHAP[v2] auth not performed.
Connection terminated.
```

Any hint how to set this from terminal?